# How to check if the hls url is protected with DRM?

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have a hls url of a video from server. And I would like to check whether the content is DRM protected. Is there any way to check a hls url is protected in iOS programmatically ?

Comment: You could download the root manifest file as text and inspect that to see if it contains the keys related to the DRM you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the container being used, the video metadata will include information to show that the video is encrypted and the manifest, the m3u8 file that is the top level index for the HLS stream, will also contain encryption information.

The quickest way is usually to check the manifest, as mentioned in the comments.

You can scan the manifest, which is usually a relatively small text file, for the term 'EXT-X-KEY' - this is used to include protection system information and if it is present the file is usually encrypted.

The HLS RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216) contains more information including this summary:

> Media Segments MAY be encrypted.  The EXT-X-KEY tag specifies how to
> decrypt them.  It applies to every Media Segment and to every Media
> Initialization Section declared by an EXT-X-MAP tag that appears
> between it and the next EXT-X-KEY tag in the Playlist file with the
> same KEYFORMAT attribute (or the end of the Playlist file).  Two or
> more EXT-X-KEY tags with different KEYFORMAT attributes MAY apply to
> the same Media Segment if they ultimately produce the same decryption
> key.  The format is:

> #EXT-X-KEY: <attribute-list>

An example manifest might look like this:

```js
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://your_license_server/your.key"
#EXTINF:4, no desc
video-audio=65000-video=360000-0.ts
```